# How to log out account in bq command in Bigquery

Tags: command-line, google-bigquery

In `bq` command, I am using a google account to login or authentication.

However, I want to change this account to another account (google account).

What's command line I can try?

Comment: Using gcloud SDK, you may use the command 'gcloud auth' with flags '-revoke' or '-login' to manage bq accounts.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command you are looking for is

```
gcloud auth login
```

After which you can switch between account by running `bq auth list` to see the credentialed accounts and then use `bq config set account <jdoe@email.com>` to switch between them.

Or if you just want to log out as asked in the question:

```
gcloud auth revoke
```